# delete of some special points

Tags: plotting

I wan to delete some points in this picture

```
f[x_] := E^x - a x;
g[x_] := a x - Log[x];

Manipulate [
 Plot[{f[x] /. a -> 1, g[x] /. a -> 1, b},
  {x, -2, 4},
  Mesh -> {{0, 0}},
  MeshFunctions -> ({(f[#] /. a -> 1) - b &, (g[#] /. a -> 1) - b &}),
  MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]],
 {{b, 1.5}, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
    Manipulate[
 Show[{Plot[{f[x] /. a -> 1 , b}, {x, -2, 4}, Mesh -> {{0, 0}},
    MeshFunctions -> ({(f[#] /. a -> 1) - b &(*,(g[#]/. a\[Rule]1)-
       b&*)}),
    MeshStyle -> {Darker[Green], PointSize[Large]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}],
   Plot[{g[x] /. a -> 1  }, {x, -2, 4}, Mesh -> {{0, 0}},
    MeshFunctions -> ({ (g[#] /. a -> 1) - b & }),
    MeshStyle -> {Darker[Green], PointSize[Large]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red]}], {{b, 1.5}, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: It feels like it wasn't handled perfectly

Comment: I think it's ok. I'll work on it myself

Comment: Isn't it the answer you are looking for?

Comment: It's what I want. I wasn't really looking